# "javax.ws.rs.NotFoundException: HTTP 404 Not Found" occurring after request

Tags: java, tomcat8, jersey-2.0

I'm working on a Java8 Tomcat8 Jersey2 web app and it's randomly logging a bizarre exception after successfully responding to requests. I have a filter in place for all requests to do some logging and add some values to the MDC (e.g. `requestId`) and the exception is coming from here. Here's the stack:

```
- HTTP 404 Not Found 
javax.ws.rs.NotFoundException: HTTP 404 Not Found
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$2.run(ServerRuntime.java:323)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:271)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:267)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:267)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:317)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:305)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:1154)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.serviceImpl(WebComponent.java:473)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:427)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:388)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:341)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:228)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at com.xyz.gatorws.webapp.LoggingFilter.doFilter(LoggingFilter.java:34)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:543)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:678)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:609)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:810)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1623)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

The odd thing is though that the request was successfully processed and a success response (200 sent back to the calling client before this stack is showing up. I'm at a loss. Also, the line in the stack coming from my code (`com.xyz.gatorws.webapp.LoggingFilter.doFilter(LoggingFilter.java:34)`) is the following:

```
chain.doFilter(httpRequest, response);
```

This is bizarre given that the filter runs before the request is processed. Argh! I must be missing something. I clear the logging context in the `LoggingFilter.destroy()` method so I can't see that another request is involved, but I'm really at a loss.

Any thoughts would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

In case this can help the asker or others

My configuration was Java9 Tomcat9 Jersey2. I got a problem like this one cause the matched method wasn't annotated with any HTTP method annotation. In my case the @GET was missing. The method was returning a Response object and after the last statement before the `return Response ...` it was throwing `NotFoundException`. I think Jersey thought this method was a subresource locator that was found due to the @Path annotation.

So i changed from this:

```
@Path("unique/page")
@Consumes("*/*")
@RolesAllowed("owner")
public Response getUnique(@PathParam("userUUID") String userUUID) throws RuntimeException {
    LogNdc.log("userUUID: " + userUUID);
    SearchCompanieService scs = new SearchCompanieService();
    CompanyPagePojo cpp = scs.searchByFieldNameAutoCommit("userPojoOwnerId", userUUID);
    System.out.println(cpp);
    return Response.status(Status.OK).entity(cpp).build();
}
```

To this:

```
@Path("unique/page")
@GET
@Consumes("*/*")
@RolesAllowed("owner")
    public Response getUnique(@PathParam("userUUID") String userUUID) throws RuntimeException {
        LogNdc.log("userUUID: " + userUUID);
        SearchCompanieService scs = new SearchCompanieService();
        CompanyPagePojo cpp = scs.searchByFieldNameAutoCommit("userPojoOwnerId", userUUID);
        System.out.println(cpp);
        return Response.status(Status.OK).entity(cpp).build();
```

}

But in my case the request was not generating any 200 response code due to the exception,  the client was getting 500 because I had a RuntimeExceptionMapper.